# select the last position of 3each driver in a SQL table with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

today i bring a SQL-Hibernate doubt.

I´ve got a table(id, xPosition, yPosition, driverName) to store the positions of the drivers.

And now i want to take the last position of everydriver (each time that a driver sends a position is stored in a new row).

I´ve done one solution, but i don´t know if is the best

```
public List<Posicion> selectAllLastPositions(){

    List<Posicion> listAllConductores = new ArrayList<Posicion>();
    List<Posicion> listLastPosiciones = new ArrayList<Posicion>();

    try{
        initQuery();
        Criteria criteria = mSession.createCriteria(Posicion.class);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("conductor")));
        listAllConductores = (List<Posicion>)criteria.list();
        for (Posicion posicion : listAllConductores) {
            Posicion pos = selectLastPosicionByConductor(posicion.getmConductor());
            listLastPosiciones.add(pos);
        }
    } catch (HibernateException e){
        manejaExcepcion(e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        mSession.close();
    }

    return listLastPosiciones;
}

public Posicion selectLastPosicionByConductor(String conductor){
    Posicion pos = new Posicion();
    try{
        initQuery();
        Criteria criteria = mSession.createCriteria(Posicion.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("conductor", conductor));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("idposicion"));
        pos = (Posicion) criteria.list().get(0);
    } catch (HibernateException e){
        manejaExcepcion(e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        mSession.close();
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Thanks to everyone and sorry about my English!

Answer (score 1):

I've never user criteria api in hibernate. But as simple query i would get this information selecting max id grouping by driverName

```
select max(id) from Table group by driverName
```

I assume that driverName is unique driver identifier. 
You have query now and you know criteria api so implement it ;]